# Spurious horizontal space in the aligned environment

Tags: spacing, align

If you compile what's below, you'll observe a slight horizontal misalignment between the equations of `aligned` versus `align`. Is there a way to avoid that?

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
text
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&A\\
&B
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
text
\begin{align}
&A\\
&B
\end{align}
text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is bizarre, but fixable. The control of the `aligned` environment in the [`amsmath` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) is governed by the command `\start@aligned`. In [`amsmath.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsmath.sty), the start of this command resembles:

```
\newcommand{\start@aligned}[2]{%
    \RIfM@\else
        \nonmatherr@{\begin{\@currenvir}}%
    \fi
    \savecolumn@ % Assumption: called inside a group
    \null\,%
    ...
```

The problem is the use of `\null\,` which adds a (spurious) `\thinspace` after `\null`, causing the misalignment. Use the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\patchcmd` to fix/patch this. Try

```
...
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\start@aligned}{\null\,}{\null}{}{}%
\makeatother
...
```

in your preamble after loading `amsmath`:

[image: Corrected aligned and align environments of amsmath]

Comment: thanks, I'll try that. Do you think it is a bug in the `amsmath package`? What about modifying it?

Comment: The `\patchcmd` command modifies during compilation, but doesn't change it in the original file `amsmath.sty`. To modify this in future releases, I would suggest submitting it as a possible bug by clicking on the [Technical Support](http://www.ams.org/cgi-bin/fmail/fmail.cgi?emailto=52616e646f6d4956b4d77092cc496a29cdfefd78c101ce0faaffd78c8ca1368b386a067ac231ca44&name=Technical%20Support) address on the [AMS website](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amslatex), or send an email to `tech-support@ams.org`.

Comment: sounds like it is a bug. They'll try to provide a solution or at least investigate, as soon as possible, as they say. Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand why they do not correct this bug? Why don't they update `amsmath.sty` on CTAN? Strange.