# amsmath updates and package history

Tags: amsmath, update

I just noticed that the amsmath package was updated lately. Sadly, I am unable to find the package history? `texdoc amsmath` does not seem to help and the documentation available online seems limited.

Comment: What exactly do you need to know?

Comment: @JosephWright In the past, the `align` environment would not exactly line up on the left for instance. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26416/spurious-horizontal-space-in-the-aligned-environment Has this been fixed for instance?

Comment: Looking at `2.15a` the issue with the extra `\,` persists. But updating typesetting features of amsmath is a delicate topic that does not just affect one or two users. Testing the code from the linked question, i cannot spot any issue.

Comment: fixing the `\,` is tricky as you'd need to make it optional or to detect whether a `\!` correction has already been applied otherwise just removing the "spurious" `\,`  is likely to cause over-printing (or bat least bad spacing)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But this could be announced in a changelog file, couldn't it be? I currently have the correction in my files but if you tell me that the issue as been fixed, I will remove it.

Comment: it's not current documents that are the worry it is 30 years worth of existing documents that expect to be run on new installations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The amsmath changelog has always been in the README linked from

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latex-amsmath

so I kept to that for now at least.

changes since 2000 are

```
V. CHANGE LOG (REVERSE CHRONOLOGICAL ORDER)

2016-03-03 amsmath.dtx 2.15a
     One missing % added to mathstrut handling.


2016-02-20 amsmath.dtx 2.15
     Updates for new \mathchardef handling in luatex
     Fix for \long macros after \dots
     (such as \iff as redefined by this package)

2013-01-14 amsmath.dtx 2.14

    * amsmath.sty 2.14
      -- Minimal changes to make amsmath compatible with stix.sty.
```

Comment: ok, sorry, I missed that file.